# Modal Controller is still top most view Controller when dismissed

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, window, hierarchy, dismiss

I have to view controllers : ContainerController, the main viewController, and VC2. VC2 is presented modally from  ContainerController. When clicking on a button in VC2, VC2 is dismissed and we are back in ContainerController. But it appears that, even when dismissed, the top most view controller is still VC2, not ContainerController. Why is this happening?
Then,when I try to present a vc like SFsafaryVC, I get an error :

> Attempt to present /SFSafariViewController: 0x10481a000/ on
>   /ContainerController: 0x1110074c0/ whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy

How can I remove VC2 from top most view controller? Or how can I bring ContainerController back on top of the stack?

Here is some code:

ContainerController :

```
class ContainerController: UIViewController {


 var isBackFromCV2: Bool = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if isBackFromCV2 {
          backFromVC2()
          }
  }
[...]

func toVC2() {
let vc = VC2()
self.present(vc, animated: true)
}

func backFromVC2() {
//some code for azure client login using SFSafariVC - needs to be presented from ContainerController
client.login(withProvider: "", urlScheme: "myApp", controller: self, completion: loginBlock)

//I tried to get the topController to check which controller is presenting
        if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
            {
              while (topController.presentedViewController != nil)
              {
                topController = topController.presentedViewController!
                print(topController) //always prints VC2
              }
            }
 }
}
```

And VC2 :

```
class VC2 : UIViewController {
let containerController = ContainerController()
[...]

func onClick() {
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  self.containerController.isBackFromVC2 = true
}

}
```

Comment: It is quite difficult to follow the hierarchy of your structure. Are you able to post a more readable format ? Or share a screenshot of your heirarchy

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I added some code, hopefully it will make my question clearer !

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this issue by setting the rootViewController to ContainerController.

In ContainerController:

```
func backFromVC2() {

  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
  appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = self
  client.login(withProvider: "yourProvider", urlScheme: "myApp", controller: self, completion: loginBlock)
   }
```

And it works fine! :)